# Creating a knob - but how to offset a circle inside another circle?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm learning Android Studio, and I'm trying to create a basic knob in .xml so that I can customize it. I'm trying to keep my design minimal, and very simple, so all I want is a circle, with a small dot near the edge, like this:

[image]

This is what I have been able to come up with so far (I know it's not much):
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="1dp"/>
            <size android:width="160dp"
                android:height="160dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Can anyone help guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple [LayerList drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList) that will produce the image below. If you want a photo-realistic button, that will be more work.

```
<layer-list>
    <item
        android:width="160dp"
        android:height="160dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="16dp"
        android:height="16dp"
        android:left="110dp"
        android:top="110dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

`width` and `height` on the items requires API 23+. There are probably other ways to do this, but this can get you started.

Comment: this is a very good start! I actually don't want anything photorealistic. I'm going for super basic right now. All I'm planning on doing is having the user be able to "rotate" the knob, so the little dot acts as a visual indicator. That should be possible with this, right? Thank you very much for your help!